# java - hibernate search indexing not working

Tags: java, spring, lucene, hibernate-search

I m trying to integrate hibernate search in my existing application. According to the tutorial of hibernate search i have added following properties in hibernate properties in applicationContext.xml

```
<prop key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">org.hibernate.search.store.FSDirectoryProvider</prop>  
<prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">./lucene/indexes</prop>
```

Also i have added the annotation on the entity classes for which i want to enable search.
Using @Indexed on class and @Field on the fields.

Following are the versions i am using (I'm not using maven):

- hibernate-search - 3.2.0.Final
- hibernate-commons-annotations 4.0.1.Final
- hibernate-core - 4.1.11 Final
- hibernate-entitymanager - 3.4.0.GA
- spring - 3.2.2 REALEASE
- lucene-core - 3.2.0

and I'm using this sample code to perform a search in MySQL database :

```
public void search() {

FullTextSession searchSession = Search.getFullTextSession(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());

QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_32, "contenu", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_32));

org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = parser.parse("décarbonateront");

org.hibernate.Query hibQuery = searchSession.createFullTextQuery(query, Book.class);

List result = hibQuery.list();

System.out.println("lucene results: " + result.size());

}
```

But I get this error : `The type org.hibernate.classic.Session cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`

at : `searchSession.createFullTextQuery(query, Book.class);`

What can be the problem ??

Comment: add hibernate.jar in your classpath to solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to align the Hibernate and Hibernate Search versions. You need Hibernate 3.5.x for Hibernate Search 3.2. Check the versions for example in the Maven pom - https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/hibernate/hibernate-search-parent/3.2.0.Final/hibernate-search-parent-3.2.0.Final.pom.

You could also download the Hibernate Search distribution from Sourceforge. The distribution contains all the right dependencies as well.